# Why change of transformation matrix is unique

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be an $n$ -dimensional vector space and let $B, B^{\prime}$ be two ordered bases for $V .$ Prove $P_{B B^{\prime}}$ is the
only matrix with the following property:
$$
[v]_{B^{\prime}}=P_{B B^{\prime}}[v]_{B}
$$

So somehow I have to show if $P_{B B^{\prime}}[v]_{B}$ = $Q_{B B^{\prime}}[v]_{B}$ then $Q=P$ . I am able to show such matrix exist using linear equation and using basis property and writing out coordinates vector but I am not able to show why it is unique.

Comment: It is the matrix representation of the unique automorphism one gets on all of $V$ by extending the map taking $B_i$ to $B'_i$. If you can show the basis vectors get carried correctly and such an extension must be unique you are done. Alternatively, you could do this using only matrices, but the proof is likely to be more hands-on unless you have a lot of theorems about matrices already under your belt

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Isomorphism is not done in class using simple tools such as linear combinaton and product of matrix vector.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen What kind of theorem?

Comment: An isomorphism of vector spaces is simply a map $f: V \mapsto V$ such that $f$ is bijective and linear and $f^{-1}$ is linear. In the case of vector spaces (finite dimension) it suffices to have $f$ be a linear transformation that is either surjective or injective. If all you have are matrices, know that linear transformations are the things you get when taking an invertible matrix $A$ and defining $x \mapsto Ax$. Products of matrices correspond to compositions of the associated linear maps (and vice-versa)

Answer (score 1):

Let $e_i\in\Bbb R^n$ be the $i$th standard basis element, i.e. it's $i$th coordinate is $1$, the rest are all $0$.

Observe that for any matrix $A$ (with $n$ columns), $Ae_i$ is the $i$th column of $A$.

Then take the basis elements $b_i$ of $B$. It is easily seen that $[b_i]_B=e_i$, and thus, if for all $v$, 
$$P[v]_B\ =\ Q[v]_B$$
then, in particular it holds for $v=b_i$, hence the $i$th columns of $P$ and $Q$ are the same, for each index $i$.